Unity 2022.03.22f Upgrade and GPGS Import: Resolving Gradle Errors and 'Split Application Binary' Issues
After upgrading to Unity 2022.03.22f version and importing Google Play Games Services (GPGS),
I am continuously encountering Gradle errors while attempting to build Android App Bundles
(AAB). There were no issues with the previous 2020 version, but the problems started after the
upgrade to 2022.

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING:The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your build.gradle instead:
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
}

> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :UnityDataAssetPack:generateAssetPackManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseAssetPackManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:linkReleaseManifestForAssetPacks UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\GitHub\Exlix\Exlix\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\libs\androidx.core.core-1.2.0.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/versionedparcelable/VersionedParcel'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/v4/app/RemoteActionCompatParcelizer'

> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processApplicationManifestReleaseForBundle UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :launcher:assetPackReleasePreBundleTask
58 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 51 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)


To resolve the issue, I have taken the following measures:

Upgraded the Gradle version.
Closed Unity and deleted the 'C: \Users\user.gradle\caches' and
'C: \Users\nomea\AppData\LocalLow[package name]' folders.
Rebooted the system.

the 'Split Application Binary' option causes errors in a new project. Since the game file size exceeds 100MB, this option is essential.
The issue may be related to changes in the R8 optimization tool settings, particularly the removal
of a checkbox, in the 2022 version. This is suspected to cause compatibility issues or
configuration errors during the build process.

Check your gradle and gradle plug-in version. They have to be compatible with your unity version. You can see compability table at here
If the error persists after the version settings, you can update the gradleTemplate.properties file as follows and try again.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx**JVM_HEAP_SIZE**M
org.gradle.parallel=true
#android.enableR8=**MINIFY_WITH_R_EIGHT**
unityStreamingAssets=**STREAMING_ASSETS**
# Android Resolver Properties Start
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
# Android Resolver Properties End
**ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES**


i did it. I've solved it by importing the conflicting jetified separately and importing the GPGS without the dependency manager.
